# Printing execution flow with new line

Tags: if-statement, go, conditional-statements

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    // can't use v here, though
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 3, 20),
    )
}
```

this code is from "A Tour of GO"

Expectation:

```
9   
10   
27 >= 20     
20
```

Output:

```
27 >= 20    
9 20
```

I don't understand about this. help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Println` function will output of both `pow` functions in a single line and then it adds `\n` after returning from Println function.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    }else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }
    // can't use v here, though
    return lim
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 2, 10))
    fmt.Println(pow(3, 3, 20))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g1Nta7HcxaA)

And `10` which is the limit in first if case will never print.

```
9
10
27 >= 20
20
```

Because `pow` function is returned before in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Arguments are evaluated first, and the `Println` inside `pow` is in an `if` block so it runs conditionally.

First, the arguments to the `Println` in `main()` are evaluated. The first call to `pow` results in `9` which is less than `lim`, so `pow` itself prints nothing and returns `9`. The second call to `pow` results in `27` which is greater than `lim`, so `pow` prints `27 >= 20` and returns `20`. Then, with the arguments handled, the call to `Println` in main is executed, printing `9 20`.